# Foursquare Venue Stats

Tags: api, foursquare

As far as I can see, it's necessary to be venue manager to get [the venue stats](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/venuestats) for a specific venue.

Is that correct? - or is there some other trick you can do to get the gender/age/hour breakdowns for all the venues in a specific area?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer satisfy your question? Please mark correct if it does

Answer (score 0):

This is only available if you're the manager of the venue for privacy reasons.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/stats

> Get venue stats over a given time range. Only available to the manager
>   of a venue.